# Comparision between two different size of Array by index to index match

Tags: java, arrays

I have two array of different size .
Scenario 1.

```
A=[1,2,3]
b=[1,3,2,4]
```

Scenario 2.

```
a=[1,3,2,4]
b=[1,3,2,]
```

How to match both the array by index to index and display the result if there is any difference .
I am able to get the result when both the array has same length . but when the array size A is shorter than B or viceversa.then getting `IndexOUTofBoundexception`obvious reason is it is trying access the element which is not exist.

```
for (int j=i;j<=i;j ++)
if (A[i].equals(B[i])) {
System.out.println(A[i] + "\t " + B[i]);
} else {
NumberOfDifference++;
 System.out.println(arrayLines1[i] + "--" + arrayLines2[i]);
                }
```

If there is difference between two arrays just need to display with the element.
in scenario 2 case `Array a`has new element 4 but `Array b` has null value .

Comment: what to do if the size is different? what will be the matching criteria then?

Comment: What you want to when the size not equal ? what is the requirement ? Assume zero for missing elements ?

Comment: You haven't said what you want the result to be for the comparison to non-existent elements.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where one array has an element but the other array does not have any element?

Comment: If one array index has one element and another array has missing that element then it should display the result. And if one array is equal to another Array and additional value there . Then it should display the additional values .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obviously only compare matching indexes up to the shortest index. The question doesn't specify what you're supposed to do with the remaining elements, but, for argument's sake, let's say we just print them:

```
int sharedLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
for (int i = 0; i < sharedLength; ++i) {
    if (a[i].equals(b[i])) {
        System.out.println(a[i] + "\t" + b[i]);
    } else {
        System.out.println(a[i] + "--" + b[i]);
}

// Here, you could either use an if statement to find the longer array
// Or, more elegantly(?), just loop over both of them.
// One of these loops will not execute because the array is too short:
for (int i = sharedLength; i < a.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(a[i] + "--");
}
for (int i = sharedLength; i < b.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println("\t--" + b[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int m = A.size()
int n = B.size()

i =0 
NumberOfDifference = 0

while (i< m && i<n)
     if (a[i]==b[i]){        
             System.out.println(A[i] + "\t " + B[i]);
     }else{

         NumberOfDifference++;
         System.out.println(A[i] + "--" + B[i]);
      }
       i++;
      }
 while (i<m) {
             NumberOfDifference++;
             System.out.println(A[i] + "--" + "NO Element");     
             i++
 }
 while (i<n) {
             NumberOfDifference++;
             System.out.println("No Element" + "--" + B[i]);    
            i++; 
 }
```

Comment: This code is not working giving nullPointerexception

Comment: You need to initilize A & B

Answer (score 0):

This way allows you to find out the differing elements:

```
for (int i=0; i < Math.max(A.length, B.length); i++) {
  if (i >= A.length) {
    NumberOfDifference++;
    System.out.println( "--" + B[i]);
  } else if (i >= B.length) {
    NumberOfDifference++;
    System.out.println(A[i] + "--" );
  } else if (A[i].equals(B[i])) {
    System.out.println(A[i] + "\t " + B[i]);
  } else {
    NumberOfDifference++;
    System.out.println(A[i] + "--" + B[i]);
  }
}
```

This is the easy way:

```
Arrays.equals(A,B)
```

Comment: This is not the solution because match is to index to index . And he difference should be counted if the value on both the array index is not matched or one array has value and another array has null .

Comment: This happens in line 3 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try to iterate through the arrays using the length of the shorter array as a maximum.

For example:

```
A=[1,2,3];
B=[1,3,2,4];
// Assign the shorter length to the temporary Integer minimum length
int minimum_length = (A.length <= B.length) ? A.length : B.length
for (int count=0; count < minimum_length; count++) {
    if (A[count).equals(B[count]) {
        System.out.println(A[i] + "\t " + B[i]);
    } else {
        NumberOfDifference++;
        System.out.println(A[i] + "--" + B[i]);
}
//Now you can just add all other integers as differences to the NumberOfDifferences-Object
for (int others = A.length; others < B.length; others++) {
    NumberOfDifferences++;
    System.out.println("null" + "--" + B[i]);
}
```

This should do the Job for the one option, now I guess you could just turn around this implementation to add the same option for the case that A is longer than B.

Hope this was helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear as others have commented... 
So I make my assumptions that you need to do index by index comparison and show extra elements as well.

So you can do something like below:

1. First find array with smaller index and loop using that array:
   Let's say A=[1,2,3]
            B=[1,3,2,4]
   So we loop over A's length.

   `int size = A.length() < B.length() ? A.length() : B.length();
   for (int i=0;i < size; i++)
   {
   if (A[i].equals(B[i])) 
   {
   System.out.println(A[i] + "\t " + B[i]);
   } 
   else 
   {
   NumberOfDifference++;
   }`
2. Now you can traverse over larger array and show difference:
   Determine which array to traverse in the same way:

   `if(A.length() < B.length())
   {

   for(int i=size; i < A.length(); i++) 
   { 
   System.out.println(A[i]);
   }
   }
   else
   {
   for(int i=size; i < B.length(); i++)
   { 
   System.out.println(B[i]);
   }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

1. hi there , you can user array-list but if you insist using array
   here is my solution  :

   // you have two array: "a[]" and "b[]"

   ```
       if (a.length == b.length){ // the code that you say have have written
       }
       else if (a.length > b.length)
       {
           int temp[] = new int[a.length]; // initialize a int[] with length of array a[]
           for (int i = 0 ;b.length>i ; i++){
               temp[i] = b[i];
           }

           for (int i = b.length; a.length> i ; i++)
           {
               temp[i] = -1 ; // some vaue you know wont be in your array
           } // now you have two array with same length
           int NumberOfDifference = 0 ;
           for (int i=0 ; i<a.length;i++){
               if (a[i]==(b[i])) {
                   System.out.println("equal occured at index : " + i +" : "+ a[i] + "\t " + b[i]);
               }
               else
               {
                   NumberOfDifference++;
                   System.out.println("equal occured at index : " + i +" : "+ a[i] + "\t " + b[i]));
               }
           }

       } // a.length < b.length
       else {

           int temp[] = new int[b.length]; // initialize a int[] with length of array b[]
           for (int i = 0 ;a.length>i ; i++){
               temp[i] = a[i];
           }

           for (int i = a.length; b.length> i ; i++)
           {
               temp[i] = -1 ; // some vaue you know wont be in your array
           } // now you have two array with same length
           int NumberOfDifference = 0 ;
           for (int i=0 ; i<b.length;i++){
               if (b[i]==(a[i])) {
                   System.out.println("equal occured at index : " + i +" : "+ a[i] + "\t " + b[i]);
               }
               else
               {
                   NumberOfDifference++;
                   System.out.println("equal occured at index : " + i +" : "+ a[i] + "\t " + b[i]));
               }
           }

       }
   ```